# Does html form submit to self cause any security issues?

Tags: html, security

I tried to look through SO for similar question but I couldn't find one, also searched through the web with my best effort, sorry if it's a silly/duplicate question

The focus of my question is :

**If I have a form with a unencoded password in it, is it "safe" to pass the form back to [self] i.e. `<form action="">`**

EDIT: I would like to focus on security regarding **third parties**, assuming the user himself is NOT the hacker.

I this is a broad question, so I would like to narrow it down to:

1. does server handle submit form to self as a internal-forward thing or do it actually treat is as a normal server-to-server http call?
2. Is it possible to somehow intercept the form submit and extract the password from this action? (including things like tapping the connect between server and client??)

If anyone knows any potential security problem in general for [submit to self], feel free to leave it as answer so that future SO user might benefit from it, thanks.

Comment: Great, I made first good answer, and I got downvoted. While the other same answer get upvoted. Please, think a little before clicking.

Comment: @Jacek I know how you feel but there is no point leaving salty/unhelpful comments. If your answer is useful, it'll eventually shine through. I am not in a hurry to pick the "answer", and no amount of downvote will stop me picking your "answer" if it's actually the best answer I could find. Give some trust in the SO community and believe in yourself :D

Comment: Ok, thanks for Your comment, and sorry for the amount of my comments. The truth is that as I said, the post data must be send somewhere. But it really doesn't matter "where" if the protocol is still http. The only important thing is to check every posted data using server side veirification. If you want to, I will update my answer with more complicated form. BR.

Comment: I update my answer. BR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing safe regarding submitting data to a webpage is to **never trust the users input**.

Now regarding your 2 questions:

1. submitting the form will be handled as a regular request, albeit a POST request probably.
2. internet traffic can be captured, so if you're sending password data over the internet you'd better make sure it's over **HTTPS**.

Using a developer tool like Mozilla's FireBug it's pretty easy to change all the data that is submitted through the form. You don't even have to use your webpage, one can easily spoof a POST request to your page by using a tool like Telnet.

So I'd say it doesn't really matter what the action of the form is; use HTTPS if possible and always validate the input...

Comment: was editting the question right before you post this. I though I should include capturing internet traffic as a possible risk to remind people what level of security risk I am talking about. So I guess it's not "safe" at all? Can you think of anything else except tapping the connection?

Comment: SQL injection is 1 of them and again, it all depends on how well you validate the data that is send to your page or how well you build up your SQL statements

Comment: thanks for the post, very helpful. I was talking about server-internal redirect/forwarding in the question, can you think of a way to kinda force a form to do that (keep all traffic inside the server) and still maintain the form submitting general behaviour like data structure and able to access it like inputstream/$_POST in php (this one might be a bit hard) ?

Answer (score 1):

Whether you submit your form to the same page or not has no security implications. There are many other things you can/should do to secure your forms. Submitting-to-self is irrelevant. It *could* however pose a UX annoyance. Have you ever tried refreshing a page only to have the browser try to resubmit the form.

1. Not a redirect. Normal post. However to mitigate this UX annoyance I
   mentioned, you would redirect to the same page after doing whatever
   you need to to with the data.
2. It depends on many other things other than whether the form submits to itself or not. Starting with is your form on a secure (https) server.

Comment: quick explaination, UX is short for user experience for anyone that don't know (including me lol). That aside, good point on mentioning user experience.

Answer (score 0):

**After many updates:**

The action="" is the same as action="somefile" in sense of security. So there is nothing wrong with action="", and as far I know most websites treats forms like that. The most popular solution is to:

- At first check with PHP if there is any post data
- Check if this data is OK (safety, server side verification)
- Make something with data (save to database, mail to someone)
- Render the form with action="".

A quick example:

```
<?php
   $name = '';
   if (isset $_POST['name']) {
      $name = $_POST['name'];
      if (ctype_alpha(str_replace(' ', '', $name)) !== false) { // verify data
          // in that case name consist only letters and spaces, it is ok.
          // do something with data here, for example save to database
          header('Location: successfile'); // Remove post data after all
      }
   }

   // render form
   $name = htmlspecialchars($name); // if name was in POST, here it is!
   echo '<form action="" method="post" />'
       echo '<label id="name" name="name" value="'.$name.'" />';
   echo '</form>';
?>
```

In that case one file is doing two jobs. It checks for data and do something with it, and render form.

Please, remember that the form can be rendered using the "partly" data from submit (POST). So for example if someone enter his name with special characters, while you need name only with letters and spaces, the data is not missed. You can render form, and in input name value, you can enter the wrong posted data. 
So the form "remember" what was filled, and what was not filled.

Hope it helps

Comment: Could someone please enter a comment, why does my answer has -1? It is nice to comment before downvote.

Comment: **100% secure**? Considering that most attacks come in via a form, can you absolutely guarantee that based on solely the value of the `action` attribute?

Comment: No, but the POST data is always being checked. There is no form in the world that can not be spammed in that way. So the action="" is absolutely the same as action="anotherfile.php" in case of security.

Comment: *So the `action=""` is absolutely the same as `action="anotherfile.php"` in case of security.* So you're saying that it makes no difference. However in your answer you claim that this method is *100% secure*...

Comment: Made a simple edit. No method is 100% secure, but there is no other method. So still I don;t understand minus one, sorry.

Comment: I gave you a -1 because your answer is misleading and incomplete and ultimately will probably confuse the OP more that it will help him. The phrase *100% secure* will give him a false (and dangerous) sense of security, no matter how much you try to qualify it. Your recommendations are vague and presumptuous (what if he doesn't want to render the form again?). Your sample code is also presumptuous. And lastly, your explanation is confusing; "multi job" isn't a thing. Bottom line, it's not a good answer. That said, I would encourage you to learn from this improve your answers by helping people.

Comment: You win some, you lose some! ;-)

Comment: Ok :). Point to You. Now the downvote make sense. I will try to improve it using your suggestions :).

Comment: Informative post and interesting example +1. However, I believe this is not a direct answer to my question, which has the assumption of "the user is inputting correctly and is not abusing the system". I was more concern about what things that third parties could possibly do to it. That said, it is totally possible that a hacker would intercept a form submit, change the parameters(SQL injection?) and resubmit it, so I guess your answer is valid to a certain degree.

Comment: Thx for opinion. Could You please explain me how? If the parameters are "changed" and resubmit, in that case the form is validated once more. And the "injection data" is thrown away by your safety machanisms. And, yes it is really easy to make a script that will send bilions of post data to any form. And the action parameter is not a case, as script can send post to any url. So... You question "Does html form submit to self cause any security issues?" has one answer: not more then any other form with any other action. And that was my answer... BTW, +1 for interesting question :).

Comment: To make clear, what I'm talking about: Question: Is driving car with gasoline engine safe? Answer 1: 'It is as safe as driving diesel car. Answer 2: No it isn't look out for trees. And cars. And weather. I mean, there are milions of things that can mess up with forms. But the action parameter doesn't change anything, in terms of security.

Answer (score 0):

I was just searching for this types of posts. 
Yeah..

As far as i know, this is not a valid approach,
attacker can change the methods to download the content like he can use the parameters from POST to GET. 
We actually have tools like tamper data which is an addon to the firefox browser. We can post the data or tamper the data which is in form submit. You can add this addon to your browser and you can check out that the data can be modified by clicking tamper before submitting the form. You can also check out the online http tampers, tamper data, modifying live headers to change your data. This may also result in sql injection. 
Correct me if im wrong. :) 
Cheers.